# After sending an email to a row of a GSheet I want to get a raiting and store it into the same raw

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I collected EmailAdresses with GForm. I want to send a text throught email to one raw and ask him to rate the text. I want to save the raiting into the same line of GSheet where his data are already stored. How can I do it?

Comment: Welcome. It seems that you are asking several questions, please correct me if I am wrong. 1) how to generate an email that includes a request for rating (rating is not defined), 2) how to capture the rating, and 3) how to cross-reference the rating to the email address on the original sheet. Would you clarify this, and limit yourself to just one question.

Comment: Thank for your reflection. You are right, I am interested in three things that are in connection to each other. I will ask each of them separately.

Comment: There are any examples of triggering the sending an email after a form response. But I think that building the rating (possibly in HTML) and the options for capturing the rating will be a challenge (email or HTML page. When you redraft your question, I suggest that you expand on the scenario around the purpose and form of the rating so that users can best understand your needs.

Comment: You might find it helpful to google "Gmail survey". One of the options, I believe, is to embed a Google Form into your email. I can't comment on how various email clients will respond to this, but it is a line of research worth pursuing.